# PageSpeed inconsistent result against webpagetest.org

Tags: performance-testing, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

When testing my website performance with webpagetest I get excellent results, with my pages being fully loaded under 1s, taking aound 0.6s.

Those tests are being made using my user base location (Brazil - São Paulo), so it may be similar to their result.

But when I do check Google Search Console for the speed result it shows around 1.4s, which is too far away from the results I do have in here.

What I am in doubt is:
Is it because the speed result in Goolge Search Console is still experimental?
Or is there something wrong that I am doing on those tests?

The webpage I am testing is:

https://www.99contratos.com.br/contrato-locacao-residencial.php

And a result I get from webpagetest can be seen clicking the link bellow:

[Results](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/200512_1P_de0981d3143439833cb7eac88af74c70/)

I do appreciate all the help / tips / explanations.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in search console is 'real world data' based on visitor experiences.

It is more accurate than synthetic tests.

What you need to look at is your break-down, not just the speeds. If you have a small percentage in the "red" and "orange" (less than 20%) then you do not need to worry, those users probably have super cheap phones and or a poor 3G connection. You cannot do much about that.

What you need to think about also is where people are accessing your site from. If they are all from abroad then you need a CDN as close to them as possible as latency will ruin your site load speed (so look at your visitor stats in Google Analytics).

Look at what devices your users are accessing your site on, if they all have super cheap android phones then expect higher load times while they process the page (hard to determine).

Just to reassure you - your page scores 98 / 100 for me using Developer Tools Audit, which considering I am in the UK is plenty quick enough.

### Couple of suggestions to improve the speed

The main thing you haven't done is [inline your critical CSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/understanding-critical-css/).

This means that your 'above the fold' content can display the second all the HTML has loaded. By not having to wait for the CSS to load from a separate request this can really speed your page up on FCP and FMP, especially if someone is on a high latency connection.

Also your number of requests could be reduced by using **inline SVGs** for your icons, making your page smaller and reducing network requests (which yet again helps with round-trip latency as up to 8 requests can be completed at a time, so with 26 requests you have at least 5 round trips to the server (1 (html), 8, 8, 8, 1) ).

Answer (score 0):

The speed (in seconds, not scores) displayed on the speed test results is very influential on the test server region. The closer the test server region is, the faster the loading time will be.

Example of speed test results for your page, using servers from Australia - Sydney, Canada - Vancouver, and your base location: Brazil - São Paulo, using GTmetrix.

- [Australia - Sydney](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.99contratos.com.br/laCxqbfF) (3,2s)
- [Canada - Vancouver](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.99contratos.com.br/xPhUqOtJ) (1,9s)
- [Brazil - São Paulo](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.99contratos.com.br/uhDwGi6U) (0,8s)

So, it can be concluded LARGE POSSIBLE test server region used by Google Search Console is far from your base location.

By the way, when I open your page from Indonesia, it only takes about 0.9-1.2 seconds. So, congratulations, your page is fast!